# Hidden values in pycharm variables pane

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

While debugging in pycharm, the majority of my variables are hidden by default, and I have to click them to show the value. The same thing happens when I use the 'Evaluate Expression' tool.

Here's an image:

[image]

This just started happening recently. Is there a setting I can change so that it displays all the variables without having to click on them?

I tried upgrading to the most recent version and that didn't fix it.

Comment: This appears to be a new "feature" in recent versions of PyCharm. I've seen the same behavior using the Python plugin for IntelliJ Ultimate.

Comment: It doesn't look like there are any options in the debugger preferences to control this. There's something called "Simplified Variable View", but it appears to be unrelated. You could submit a feature request to JetBrains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch variables loading policy to something else from "On demand":

[image]